# vscode running R script

Tags: r, linux, visual-studio-code

I've installed the two R extensions (R Extension for Visual Studio Code v2.8.2, and R Debugger for VS Code v0.5.4) but am unable to launch an R script from within VSCode.

I have seen that there is (possibly) some strange issue where I have to edit settings.json, which I have done.  This now contains the following lines:

```
 "r.rpath.linux": "/usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R",
 "r.rterm.linux": "/usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R"
```

I have tried using the normal command path to R as well :  /usr/bin/R

I continue to receive the same error message

> Cannot find R client at /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R. Please check r.rterm setting.

Any ideas on what I am missing >?

Comment: On Ubuntu not having these lines works actually fine for me. Really having R under /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R?! How did you install it?

Comment: I'm running OpenSuse Tumbleweed, so I used the (default) tool "zypper" to install VSCode.

Then I used VSCode to install the extensions.

Comment: And R, did you use package manager or compile it? What does `which R` yield?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I installed R via "zypper" as well.
I selected a package "R-recommended-packages", which included all kinds of stuff.
[code]
host:~> which R

/usr/bin/R

Comment: Looks fine to me. Since I used same approach and worked for me out of the box, having no clue. Let's wait for other suggestions.

Comment: The path to the R executable indicated by the `which` utility appears different than the one implied by the json settings.

Comment: @IRTFM Yeah OP claims they tried both. Never used that setting and works like a charm.

Comment: /usr/bin/R is a symlink to /usr/lib64/R/bin/ecec/R.    Regardless of which I use, I get the same result, the error message indicates that R is not found..   if I launch R from a shell, then search for the running process vis "ps" I see the lib64 path to R.  That R is an ELF executable,

Comment: What does readlink `-f /usr/bin/R` yield? And could you finally confirm that deleting`"r.rpath.linux": "/usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R", "r.rterm.linux": "/usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R"` lines from settings.json doesn't help?

Comment: readlink /usr/bin/R returns /usr/lib64/R/bin/R (which is indeed different than /usr/lib64/R/bin/ecec/R.  So, I changed the settings.json to use that, with the same results.  FINALLY, I tried removing both //"r.rpath.linux":    //"r.rterm.linux": completely, which results in "Could not find R path. Please check r.term and r.path setting."

Comment: Great. Check `echo $PATH` if this path is included there. If not, add it via `export PATH=/usr/lib64/R/bin/:$PATH` (updating the linux PATH environment variable). If it helped you can do it permanently by adding the line to end of `nano ~/.bashrc`. To avoid restart, you can do `source ~/.bashrc` to take effect for current session.

Comment: I discovered that I somehow had two simultaneous installations of VSCode.
One of them was a "flatpack" install.  Since I have encountered numerous problems with Flatpack packages in the past, I have uninstalled that version.

Suddently, I am able to run R from within VSCode.  

I think everyone for the help.

Comment: @Smit-Tay happy you could solve the problem, ty for sharing.